# strange syntax error using function reference

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I have the following code ...

```
List<Person> personenListe = Arrays.asList(new Person[] {person1, person2,person3,person4});

        List<Person> personmitnamen4 = personenListe.stream().filter(p -> p.getName().equals("name4")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        personmitnamen4.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
        personmitnamen4.forEach(new Consumer<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Person p) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        });
        personmitnamen4.forEach(p -> System.out::println); // <- the target type of this expression must be a functional interface.
```

[image]

My `Person` class has a `toString` method declared.

... where I sysout persons in different way. But the most preferable way to do shows me a syntax error in eclipse. In IntelliJ I do not get this . Can anyone explain or tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write either

```
personmitnamen4.forEach(System.out::println);
```

which is a method reference.

or

```
personmitnamen4.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
```

which is a lambda expression.

What you attempted to pass to `forEach`:

```
p -> System.out::println
```

is a lambda expression implementing a functional interface with a method that accepts a `Person` and returns a method reference compatible with `Consumer<Person>`, which makes the lambda expression compatible with the functional interface `Function<Person,Consumer<Person>>`, which is not the `Consumer<Person>` required by `forEach`.

You can test it by observing that the following would pass compilation:

```
Function<Person,Consumer<Person>> foo = p -> System.out::println;
```

Comment: Good explained last sentence opened me new door :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should either use *lambda* or use *method reference*, not both at the same time.

```
personmitnamen4.forEach(System.out::println); // method reference

personmitnamen4.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p)); // lambda
```